# setting IP address from different subnet to virtual machines

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware-esxi

I have only 1 NIC on my server and the IP address of it is 62.X.X.107. And the gateway I've received from the datacenter is 62.X.X.1. I have bought 2 more IP addresses from the datacenter to use them for my virtual machines, but the IP addresses starts with 5! I mean they are 5.X.X.X. I'm really confused how to get it work!

Note: The virtual machines have Windows Server 2008 R2 installed on them.

Comment: Actually, how can I give an IP adddress like 5.X.X.X to a VM with the default gateway of 62.X.X.1? How can I route that!?

Comment: I used 255.255.255.255 as mask to route all the trrafic to the gateway, but it didn't work! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 5.X.X.X IPs are on-net (on the same switched network as your 62.X.X.107 IP), then the network your server is connected to has multiple subnets on it and your hosting provider should have given you a subnet mask and gateway to use with those. In that case, your server will bridge (not route) the packets to your VM; the server will act as a virtual network switch.

If the 5.X.X.X IPs are routed, then your hosting provider has created a static route that delivers those packets via your server's 62.X.X.107 IP and you need your server to route those packets into an internal VM network. The subnet mask of the 5.X.X.X network that is routed to you would have been provided.

Your hosting provider should be providing you support; they should be able to answer whether those IPs are routed or on-net and may be able to give you directions.

Comment: I enabled promiscuous mode on VMWare networking to make it bridged and used 255.255.255.255 mask and it worked!